# How to force input change trigger with ng-model-options's debounce in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm testing my library. Problem is I have debounce in the textfield to avoid often updates.

Like

```
<input ... ng-model-options="{debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0} }"
```

But I can't disable it in tests even I tried to trigger `blur`

```
it("""test input set with debounce""", function(){
    scope.obj = {
        name: 'John'
    }
    el = compileTemplate("<span><input ng-model=\"obj.name\" ng-model-options=\"{debounce: {'default': 500, 'blur': 0} }\"></input></span>")
    scope.$digest()
    input = el.find('input');
    expect(input.val()).toEqual('John');
    angular.element(input).val('Max').trigger('change').trigger('blur')
    scope.$apply()
    expect(scope.obj.name).toEqual('Max');
})
```

It'll fail because I have to add $timeout. So 10 tests = 5 seconds delay which is inappropriate.

How can I force `change` trigger to avoid debounce or trigger `blur`?

Answer (score 3):

The mocked `$timeout` service has a `flush` method, you could use to trigger the update in unit tests.

```
it('should set with debounce', inject(function ($timeout) {
    input.val('Max').triggerHandler('input');
    $timeout.flush();
    expect(scope.obj.name).toEqual('Max');
}));
```

Comment: Thanks it works. What's weird that in browser setTimeout work but in unit test don't.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like just using `$timeout` even without `delay` does the trick:

```
$timeout(function(){
    expect(scope.obj.name).toEqual('Max');
})
```